# Unity - Pause/Resume Button will trigger my jump animation - How to fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have this simple code. I have used the if statement to check that if i press the pause button, the jump animation will not be triggered. After the Paused Menu is activated, when i click resume, the game will start immediately and the character will jump straight away.
I have tried using Coroutines, with real time and time.timeScale = 0.001, but the action will still be triggered. Any ideas on how to solve?

```
private void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
               
            if (startTouchPosition.x < screenMinusButton.x || startTouchPosition.y < screenMinusButton.y)
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
}
```

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095383/detect-mouse-clicked-on-gui

Comment: I will have to learn a little bit more, I don;t know anything about that topic yet. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to putting invisible full screen panel , back of the button/menu.

Comment: I have a canvas, multiple panels, everything is done ok.

Answer (score 1):

Does the character actually jumps or it's just an animation issue ?

Try to check your rb.velocity in the inspector. If is not visibile, try to enable debug mode in the upper corner.

If the Y doesn't change maybe it's just an animation triggered wrongly

Comment: The player is jumping because in the update method, all the touches are considered jumping. I wanted to make an If or something so that if i press the buton, the player will not jump. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the EventSystem has any GameObject currently considered as active. If yes, the touch is performed over button else the touch is not over the button.

Add using UnityEngine.EventSystems; at the top of your script. Then modify your code as shown below.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == null && rb.velocity.y == 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is working partially. I am using the swipe up method now and if i press below the button and then i will press the button, the hero will still jump.

Comment: What is screenMinusButton? Is it a GUI button or anything else? Could you post your code for jump?

Answer (score 0):

Use IsPointerOverGameObject()

```
if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() && Input.touchCount > 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
}
```

I recently found the answer.